# KOrganizer: Reminders always in foreground

Tags: linux, linux-mint, kde, window-focus, organizer-software

The reminders of KOrganizer always appear in foreground and steal focus.

I can move them to another monitor but I accidentally close them with Alt+F4 as they steal focus.

How can I configure KOrganizer in a way that allows me to move these reminders to background?

I use Linux Mint 21.1 Cinnamon.

Update: There is an option "Always in foreground" when I right click the top bar of the reminder window. But when I uncheck this and switch windows, the window grabs focus again.